# Calculate a new field from multiple observations sas

Tags: sas

I am struggling to find out in SAS how best to deal with the scenario where in the sample data "alex" has two orders in 2015 and therefore I would like a new column to appear with his status = "active"

any helpful hints to get me on the right track? thanks

```
 ID     first_order      Order
 alex      01/01/2013     23/01/2015
 alex      01/01/2013     23/01/2015 
 alex      01/01/2013      03/04/2013
```

Comment: you want the `status` column to show active for the dates of 2015 only?

Comment: What is the difficulty besides assigning the variable?

Comment: you can use INTNX, DATDIF, ...

Answer (score 1):

In this example, let's assume that Alex placed one order in 2013 and another order in 2015. Bob placed just one order in 2013. Let's create some data:

```
data have;
    format id $4. first_order Order date9.;
    id = 'Alex'; first_order = '01JAN2013'd; Order = '23JAN2015'd; output;
    id = 'Alex'; first_order = '01JAN2013'd; Order = '03APR2013'd; output;
    id = 'Bob';  first_order = '01JAN2013'd; Order = '01JAN2013'd; output;
run;
```

The macro below can be used to derive the status of a customer in any given year.

```
%macro Active(year=);

proc sql;
    create table CustomerStatus as
    select id,
           case when max(year(Order)) = &year then 'Active' 
           else 'Inactive' end as Status_in_&year length=8 
    from have
    group by id
    order by id;

    create table want as
    select have.id, have.first_order, have.Order, CustomerStatus.Status_in_&year
    from have inner join CustomerStatus on have.id = CustomerStatus.id
    order by CustomerStatus.id;
quit;

%mend Active;

%Active(year=2015);
```

In table CustomerStatus we get the year of the most recent order for all customers. If this is equal to the year of an order, the customer status is Active. Finally the status is joined with the Orders table.